# IndexError: list index out of range in debug Python script

Tags: python, debugging

When I debug my Python script this error occurs in import library: (I'm using Thonny as IDE)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script_name.py", line 29, in <module>
    from builders import model_builder
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 916, in get_code
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I continue debugging?

PS. when I run the application this error does not occurs

Comment: Could you post the code that is causing the trouble?

Comment: It's specified in my question... line 29: ```from builders import model_builder```